# Antenna pattern/illumination corrections in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, geemap, sar

I am using the analysis ready Level 2.2 ALOS-2 PALSAR-2 data available in Google Earth Engine. Here is an example provided by GEE: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=Examples%3ADatasets%2FJAXA%2FJAXA_ALOS_PALSAR-2_Level2_2_ScanSAR

I have noticed there is an illumination/antenna pattern across the vertical scan lines within each image (5 scan lines), affecting different images to a greater or lesser extent. For some areas it is not noticeable at all, while for other areas some of the backscatter values seem to vary significantly across the scan lines. For example, there are differences of between 0.5 and 1 dB between some pixels in subsequent overlapping images taken on the same date.

I'll be comparing the pixels multi-temporally, so any corrections should ideally be applied in an equivalent way across the image stack.

Does anyone have any ideas about how this can be corrected? I've previously used the wide scan level 1.5 ALOS-2 PALSAR-2 data and applied a linear regression across the whole image to correct for the antenna pattern, but that option would not be suitable here due to the sub-scan lines.